# html multiple redirects depending on input

Tags: javascript

I want to make a code that are redirecting you to your site with use of a textbox popup. 
**example:**

**user1** will type **user1** and will be redirected to **user_franklin.html**

**user2** will type **user2** and will be redirected to **user_Jennifer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script>
    var pass;
pass = prompt("Skriv in dit H nummer (h501234)");
if (pass == "h504340") {
    document.location.href = "user_mathias.html";
if (pass == "h504355") {
    document.location.href = "user_sondre.html";
if (pass == "h000002") {
    document.location.href = "user_love.html";
if (pass == "h000001") {
    document.location.href = "user_haakon.html";
} else {
    document.write("Din H identitet er ikke i systemet!");
}</script>
```

Code isnt working btw.

Comment: String literals in JavaScript can be delimited by `"` or `'`, you cannot use `«`. (Voting off-topic as using the wrong kind of quote is a typo).

Comment: Code still not working after changing to "

Comment: Your `if` statements aren't written correctly. here's no `}` at the end of some of them

Comment: they should also mostly be `else if` instead of just `if`, otherwise, even if there's a match on the first `if` for example, the `else` will trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let me wheel out the standard caveat that doing any sort of user authentication in client-side JS is a terrible idea.

Like, of the same terribleness as invading Poland, by yourself, armed only with handfuls of wet grass.

A user has only to look at your JS to learn all the 'secrets'.

But I'll assume this is just a pet project where there's no real security implications.

Secondly, this can be hugely simplified.

```
(() => {
    let map = {
        h504340: 'mathias',
        h504355: 'sondre',
        h000002: 'love',
        h000001: 'haakon'
    };
    let pass = prompt("Skriv in dit H nummer (h501234)");
    if (map.pass)
        location.href = 'user_'+map[pass]+'.html';
    else
        document.write('Incorrect pass entered');

})();
```

*Always* imagine there's a better way if you find yourself writing repetitive code.

This approach maps user inputs to redirect locations. We look up what they enter in our map, and if a corresponding key exists, we go to its related page.

Note also I added a closure so as not to pollute the global scope as you were.

Finally, `document.write()`, while it does *occasionally* have legitimate use, is archaic and hardly used these days. If you want to output a message, use DOM scripting methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Quentin said in the comments, you must use `"` or `'` to delimit a `string`

Second of all, your `if/if else/else` statements aren't working properly because most of them don't close with a `}`

Third of all, besides the first `if` and the `else`, all the others should be `else if`. Otherwise if the earlier conditions match, it will not match the last condition, and therefore default to the `else`.

This code fixes your syntax errors and should work.

```js
var pass = prompt("Skriv in dit H nummer (h501234)");
    if (pass == "h504340") {
        document.location.href = "user_mathias.html";
    } else if (pass == "h504355") {
        document.location.href = "user_sondre.html";
    }else if (pass == "h000002") {
        document.location.href = "user_love.html";
    } else if (pass == "h000001") {
        document.location.href = "user_haakon.html";
    } else {
        document.write("Din H identitet er ikke i systemet!");
    }
```